# How to read and write ndef from protected blocks in Mifare Class 1k (MF1S50)?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

Currently i'm using the MF1S50 card and it follows the typical Mifare Classic structure of sectors and blocks, etc.

I'm able to read and write ndef messages when none of the blocks are protected. The message seems to consume 356 bytes which is just the first few blocks.

I'm writing using `Ndef.writeNdefMessage()` and reading using `Ndef.getNdefMessage()`.

Is it possible for me to password protect the blocks that i'm using and continue to use `Ndef.getNdefMessage` to read and `Ndef.writeNdefMessage` to write into these blocks?

(My first instinct says no its not possible). If not, what is the general procedure?
Is this how it is going to work?

Connect-> Authenticate-> Read -> Increment -> Read -> Close.

I'm guessing if this happens,

`<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />`

cannot be used right?

Answer (score 1):

In case of NDEF stored on a MIFARE Classic card, key A for reading the contents of the sectors is fixed so that any NFC device can access the contents. However, you can change key B and configure the sectors such that key A can only be used to read the message and not overwrite it.

Comment: I got that key B has to be used. But i cannot use the ndef class can i? also, i cant handle them in onNewIntent coz that would mean a user has tapped and gone. If i use MifareClassic class then connect function will fail coz the tag wont be there :/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "use the ndef class". Storing an NDEF message on a MIFARE Classic tag requires the use of certain Key A. Key B can be changed to whatever you want to protect the content. Whenever an NFC intent is triggered, it will be received in your app in `onNewIntent()` or `onCreate()`. That has nothing to do with the tag being there or not.

Comment: well, does key authentication happen AFTER the intent data is passed?

Comment: No,  before. Otherwise the tag contents cannot be accessed.